Does "Lord" in the NT, after the Gospels, predominantly refer to Jesus, except for when the OT is in view? (Limiting to Acts 1-5 for now)
Does "Lord" in Acts 1-5 predominantly refer to Jesus, except for when the OT is in view? (Am strictly interested in when kurios is used to refer to divinity.)
[I am ultimately interested in answering this question for the whole of the NT, other than the Gospels, and I've got a few interesting passages that I want to get to later, but let's keep this present question bite-sized.]
Here are a couple specific verses to engage over:
Acts 1:24. Are they praying to Jesus? Note that they just referred to Jesus as Lord in Acts 1:21.
Acts 2:20. Should "the day of the Lord" be understood as "the day of Jesus"? I assume that 2:21 is about calling on the name of Jesus for salvation.
Acts 2:39. Is Jesus in view when the passage says that it is "the Lord our God" who is calling people to Himself? Note that 2:36 states that "God has made Him both Lord and Christ" and 2:38 is also referring to Jesus.
Acts 2:47. Is Jesus the one who is adding to their number or is it the Father, given the context of the above Lord usages?
Acts 3:20 (ESV). Do the times of refreshing which "come from the presence of the Lord" refer to Jesus? Both the Father and Jesus are addressed within the broader passage. I can see either one as being the referent.
Acts 5:14. Does more "believers were added to the Lord" refer to Jesus?
Certain other passages are clearly or likely referencing the Father. Such as
Acts 4:26, 29. Lord here is clearly with reference to the Father, given the references to "your holy servant Jesus."
Acts 5:9. Am assuming that "Spirit of the Lord" likely refers to the Father; but am open to a different approach.

If the Book of Acts is the focal point on Lord and the question of Father and Son. You should consider "Father" is used in 1:4, 7, and 2:33. After 2:33 that term is never used. It is apparent Luke chose to describe the development of the Church by purposely avoiding any reference to the Father.

This is ultimately a question of translator choice.  The Bible I use most frequently has a preface that discusses, among other things, translation conventions used for various names of God.  I am not confident that such conventions can be relied upon to be the same from one translation to another.

@John Bollinger. I'm specifically chasing instances where the Greek uses forms of kurios, so these are not translation conventions, but exegetical decisions to be made be the reader.

If that's what you mean, @Dan, then you should edit the question to say that.

OK, am addeding some kurios qualifications to the question.

@DanMoore. Limiting the  answers to the question with what is written only in Acts 1-5 is really not biblical hermeneutics. If verses have more than one interpretation, these verses need to be understood in light of other verses on the same subject that are explicit and unequivocal.

@AlexBalilo. Yes, other passages are pertinent; however, I'm not trying to establish a hard rule that all "Lord" passages in the NT refer to Jesus, but merely that in the NT (or more specifically in this chunk of Acts) they tend to. My first post to the Hermeneutics forum asked a broad question, and the input was that I needed to restrict questions to specific passages, so here we are.

Let us examine the actual data in all 18 instances of "Lord" in Acts 1-5 -

Acts 1:6 - So when they came together, they asked Him, “Lord, will You at this time restore the kingdom to Israel?”  [refers to JESUS]
Acts 1:21 - Therefore it is necessary to choose one of the men who have accompanied us the whole time the Lord Jesus went in and out among us [refers to JESUS]
Acts 1:24 - And they prayed, “Lord, You know everyone’s heart. Show us which of these two You have chosen [not obvious]
Acts 2:20 - The sun will be turned to darkness, and the moon to blood, before the coming of the great and glorious Day of the Lord [Quoting from Joel 2:28-32 referring to Jehovah]
Acts 2:21 - And everyone who calls on the name of the Lord will be saved.’ [Quoting from Joel 2:28-32 referring to Jehovah]

This deserves some extra examination.  According to Rom 10 we have that "Jesus is Lord" and the source of salvation:

8 But what does it say? “The word is near you; it is in your mouth and in your heart,” that is, the word of faith we are proclaiming:
9 that if you confess with your mouth, “Jesus is Lord,” and believe in your heart that God raised Him from the dead, you will be
saved. 10 For with your heart you believe and are justified, and
with your mouth you confess and are saved.
11 It is just as the Scripture says: “Anyone who believes in Him will never be put to shame.” 12 For there is no difference between
Jew and Greek: The same Lord is Lord of all, and gives richly to
all who call on Him, 13 for, “Everyone who calls on the name of
the Lord will be saved.”

Thus, it rather obvious that Paul believed that not only "Jesus is Lord" and "The same Lord is Lord of all", and hence, "Everyone who calls on the name of
the Lord will be saved".  Hence, the NT teaches that Jesus is the "Lord" that saves and so is the same Lord of all that is referenced in Acts 2:21.
To continue our listing:

Acts 2:25 - David says about Him: ‘I saw the Lord always before me; because He is at my right hand, I will not be shaken. [According to V24 the "him" is JESUS.]
Acts 2:24 - For David did not ascend into heaven, but he himself says: ‘The Lord said to my Lord, “Sit at My right hand ... [Only one of these is Jesus, the other is the Father.]
Acts 2:36 - Therefore let all Israel know with certainty that God has made this Jesus, whom you crucified, both Lord and Christ!” [this one is self-explanatory]
Acts 2:39 - This promise belongs to you and your children and to all who are far off—to all whom the Lord our God will call to Himself.” [Again, according to John 12:32, Jesus draws all men to Himself by His crucifixion.  And, according Titus 2:13, Jesus is also God.  So this verse "Lord" is Jesus.]
Acts 2:47 - praising God and enjoying the favor of all the people. And the Lord added to their number daily those who were being saved. [not obvious]
Acts 3:20 - that times of refreshing may come from the presence of the Lord, and that He may send Jesus, the Christ, who has been appointed for you. [This appears to be the Father who sends Jesus.]
Acts 3:22 - For Moses said, ‘The Lord your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among your brothers. You must listen to Him in everything He tells you. [not obvious but perhaps the Father]
Acts 4:26 - The kings of the earth took their stand, and the rulers were gathered together against the Lord and against His Christ.' [This refers to the Father]
Acts 4:29 - And now, Lord, consider their threats, and enable Your servants to speak Your word with complete boldness [according to V30, this refers to the Father]
Acts 4:33 - With great power the apostles continued to give their testimony about the resurrection of the Lord Jesus. And abundant grace was upon them all.
Acts 5:9 - “How could you agree to test the Spirit of the Lord?” Peter replied. “Look, the feet of the men who buried your husband are at the door, and they will carry you out also.” [not obvious as the Holy Spirit is spoken of as both the Spirit of God and the Spirit of Christ.]
Acts 5:14 - Yet more and more believers were brought to the Lord—large numbers of both men and women. [I would argue this refers to Jesus as we follow Jesus.  Only Jesus asked people to "follow me".]
Acts 5:19 - But during the night an angel of the Lord opened the doors of the jail and brought them out, saying... [According to Matt 13:41, 24:31, Mark 13:27, it is Jesus who commands angels.]

Thus, most references to "Lord" in this sample refer to Jesus.  Only a few refer to the Father.
There is another significant instance of "Lord" in Acts 7:59, 60 -

(Acts 7:59, 60): While they were stoning him, Stephen called out,
“Lord Jesus, receive my spirit.” Falling on his knees, he cried out in
a loud voice, “Lord, do not hold this sin against them.” And when he
had said this, he fell asleep.

There are two things that are significant about this:

That Stephen prayed to “Lord Jesus” at all, implying Jesus was divine
That Stephen asked Jesus to receive his breath/spirit.  This is a direct allusion to at least two OT passages:


Ps 31:5 - Into Your hands I commit my spirit/breath; You have redeemed me, O LORD, God of truth.
Eccl 12:7 - before the dust returns to the ground from which it came and the spirit/breath returns to God who gave it.
In both cases, Stephen obviously believed that Jesus was the God who receives his breath/life as he died.  This is the reverse of what is recorded in Gen 2:7 where God bequeaths the breath of life to man (Adam).

Thus, Acts 7:59 is a perfect example of Stephen praying to Jesus as "Lord".
We also have the following statements in the NT:

1 Cor 12:3 - Therefore I make known to you that no one speaking in the Spirit of God says, "Jesus is accursed," and no one is able to say, "Jesus is Lord," if not in the Holy Spirit.
Rev 17:14 - These will make war with the Lamb, and the Lamb will overcome them, because He is Lord of lords and King of kings; and those with Him are called and chosen and faithful."
Rev 19:16 - And He [Jesus] has a name having been written upon the robe and upon His thigh: King of Kings and Lord of Lords.

These last two texts directly allude to Deut 10:17, Ps 136:3, 26 where Jehovah is described as "Lord of Lords".

Acts 10:36 - the word that He sent to the sons of Israel, proclaiming the gospel, peace by Jesus Christ--He is Lord of all.
Rom 10:12 - For there is no difference between Jew and Greek; for the same Lord of all is rich toward all those calling Him,
see also Col 1:15

These last three verses directly allude to Jesus as Jehovah who is "Lord of All", in Deut 10:17, Josh 3:11, 13, Ps 97:5, Zech 4:14, 6:5, Mic 4:13.

+1 Nice. The answer could be improved by including 1 Corinthians 8:6 which makes explicit Christians have one Lord and therefore passages which speak of or about Judaism which denies Jesus is Lord need to be examined in the proper context. IOW, a non-believers use of Lord is subject to interpretation but a believer's use of Lord is not.

Wow. You put a lot into this. Thanks. I appreciate the methodical review and that you've made the case the (1) Jesus can be the recipient of prayer and that (2) Jesus can be the Lord who is in view, even when an OT passage is being invoked.

So, given what you've demonstrated, it seems reasonable to treat the Acts 1:24 prayer as being made to Jesus, yes? But what about Acts 2:20? Since you've made the case that the citation of an OT "Lord" passage can be understood within the NT as referring to Jesus, can the invocation of the Joel passage not be understood this way? Am going to need to dig into other passages which might bring clarity to the Acts 2:47 passage.

@DanMoore - I tried to keep within the scope of the question.  Obviously, extending this to rest of the NT would show a similar patter and prayers to Jesus and numerous OT passage about YHWH are used in the NT to refer to Jesus.

Up-voted +1. Very edifying just to read through this list of quotations. Much appreciated.

In the list of Acts scriptures, it would be most remiss to leave out this one. The context is one of the disciples having been falsely accused of speaking blasphemously against Moses and God. He gives his defense, proving he knows and honours Moses, and the one God. But when he gets to including mention of Jesus Christ (how his accusers had betrayed and murdered him) they set to stone him :

"But he, being full of the Holy Spirit, looked up steadfastly into
heaven, and saw the glory of God, and Jesus standing on the right hand
of God. And said, Behold, I see the heavens opened, and the Son of man
standing on the right hand of God..."
And they stoned Stephen, calling upon God, and saying, Lord Jesus,
receive my spirit... Lord, lay not this sin to their charge." Acts
7:51-60 A.V.

This shows a Christian man, full of the Holy Spirit, seeing the glory of God and the risen Christ in heaven in vision, and not only addressing Christ as 'Lord' but praying to him. Further, in the preceding verses, he also referred to the God of the O.T. as 'Lord'. So, why would he also call this risen Christ his Lord, who he prays to, if Christians had not come to believe that Christ is both Lord and God? (Jude vs.4, 1 Tim.1:2) Stephen already knew of Thomas having declared the risen Christ to be his Lord and his God in John's gospel.
However, the question asks if there is a predominance of Jesus being referred to as "Lord" after the N.T. Gospels except when the O.T. is in view. That would entail counting the number of verses involved, so the scope cannot remain within that of the 12 verses in Acts that you specifically ask about (or even all the occurrences in the entire book of Acts).
Yet, searching that chapter in Acts for numeric significance, I find that Stephen mentions 'Lord' a total of seven times. Five time with respect to the God of the O.T. (his angel x 1, his voice x 1, and his invisible person x 3.) Twice he refers to 'Lord' as the risen Christ. Given that 50 verses deal purely with the O.T., and the remaining 9 verses deal only within the N.T. setting, I offer this answer as a valid example of taking verses in the book of Acts as an example of considering a numeric answer.
Also given that a requirement is also "to keep the present question bite-sized", I will say no more.

+1 . You might include 1 Corinthians 8:6 which makes explicit Christians have one Lord. Passages which speak of or about Judaism which denies Jesus is Lord need to be examined in the proper context. IOW, a non-believers use of Lord is not only subject to interpretation; it cannot be used in any meaningful way to determine the believer's use.

Thanks, Anne. So for Acts 7, it can be said that 100% of the Lord references, which are not overtly tied to the OT, are with reference to Jesus, yes? (Dottard has kindly shown that some OT "Lord" passages are understood in the NT to refer to Jesus, but the Acts 7 passage does not seek to do such.)

@RevelationLad  The OP was hoping to keep this initial Q to the first 5 chapters in Acts. I exceeded that by dealing with all of chapter 7! But I hope it's still acceptable.

@DanMoore The only 2 times 'Lord' is said in Acts 7 where the risen Christ is meant, are at the very end, and with regard to prayer. But note that Stephen says 'God' 17 times, in the whole chapter, only the last 3 times referring to God in a N.T. setting, not O.T. He does not qualify 'God' those 3 times with 'Lord'. Yet the twice he addresses Jesus, it is connected to 'Lord'. It's all girst to the mill.

Introduction
The term “Lord” in the NT, including the Gospels, officially refers to Jesus Christ by apostolic authority.
The slogan of faith in the New Testament taught by the apostles in authority is this:

“but to us there is one God, the Father, of whom are all things,
and we for Him, and one Lord Jesus Christ, through whom are all
things, and we by Him. But the knowledge is not in all” (1 Cor 8:6-7).

So, who is the Lord in the NT?
It is Jesus Christ.
Now does that mean God the Father cannot be Lord? No, God the Father is called Lord in the NT.
Again, does that mean Lord Jesus cannot be God? No, Lord Jesus is called God in the NT.
Meaning of the Term “God”
The Greek Septuagint was translated around 250 years before Christ. They left a great legacy of translation.
They have consistently translated the Hebrew term “Elohim” as “Theos” in Greek which in turn was translated as “God” in English.
The personal name of the God of the OT, “Yahweh” was translated as “Kurios” in Greek which in turn was translated into English as “Lord”. They translated Hebrew “Adonai” also as “Kurios” in Greek, again “Lord” in English.
So we see:
Elohim = Theos = God
Yahweh = Kurios = Lord
Adonai = Kurios = Lord
The word “Elohim” that ended up as “God” is actually a plural word used as singular with singular verbs in the Bible. But it is also used as a plural word with plural verbs. “Elohim” can be considered as similar to words like “family”, “team”, “church”, “nation” etc.
So, when Jesus Christ qualified the Father as “the only true God” (a favorite of the Unitarians), what He meant was “you are the only true Elohim”. Now, Elohim is not an “exclusive” term but it is “inclusive”. It included Lord Jesus also.
This is how, Jesus “is Elohim and with Elohim” (as in John 1:1)!
Lord Jesus & His Apostles
Interestingly and surprisingly, Jesus Christ and His apostles followed the same tradition. Jesus called His Father, God. Noticeably, He never called Him as LORD. Only when Jesus referred to OT quotations involving Yahweh, the term “Lord” is used. But He doesn’t seem to add ‘Father’ there.
To the apostles, as we saw above, the Lord predominantly referred to Jesus.
Why Holy Spirit is Needed to call Jesus Lord
Sara called Abraham ‘lord’ without the help of Holy Spirit.
If ‘Lord” simply meant master, teacher or owner, then the assistance of Holy Spirit is not required to an individual to call Jesus Lord.
But Apostle Paul says:

“And no one is able to say Jesus is Lord, except by the Holy
Spirit” (1 Cor 12:3).

Why is such a strong statement from an apostle?
The reason is that Jesus is the Yahweh of the Old Testament!
Yahweh says in Isaiah 45:23-24:

“I have sworn by Myself, the Word has gone out of My mouth in
righteousness, and shall not return, that to ME (i.e., Yahweh)
every knee shall bow, every tongue shall swear. He shall say, Only in Jehovah do I have righteousness and strength”

Quoting this OT verse, Paul says:

“that at the name of JESUS "every knee should bow," of heavenly
ones, and earthly ones, and ones under the earth, and "every tongue
should confess" that Jesus Christ is "Lord, (i.e., Yahweh)" to the
glory of God the Father” (Philipp 2:10-11).

Paul cannot be plainer than the above and hence I have no further comments to make here.
Answer
Now to answer the OP’s particular question, a lot of ambiguity could be found in identifying each and every ‘Lord” in the first chapters of Acts. This is because the apostles did not do a good job in pinpointing each ‘Lord’ used in the NT. This is because, to them, it didn’t make much difference! They knew that the effect or result would be the same.
They were well aware of the fact that Jesus said:

“The one seeing Me has seen the Father!” (John 14:9); “If you had
known Me, you would have known My Father also” (John 14:7); “And the
one seeing Me sees the One who sent Me” (John 12:45).

Because:

“I and the Father are One!”

Explanation
If it required a hair splitting analysis to identify which Lord was the Father and which Lord was the Son, the apostles would have made it carefully very clear in the Scripture.
After all, considering a “creature” at par with the Creator would be nothing less than sin. But still they all were “careless”!
The fact, that they left a lot of ambiguity in the Scripture about who the Lord is, shows clearly that, to them, it had the same effect.
Who Answers the Prayer?
They knew that Jesus said both:

“Whatever you shall ask the Father in My name, He will give you”
(John 16:23).


“If you ask anything in My Name, I will do it” (John 14:14).

So, actually who will do it?
The answer is; the result is the same becasue Father and Son are One.
Who Receives Worship?
The apostles knew also that God the Father is worthy to be worshipped; Jesus Christ also is worthy to be worshipped:

“Lord (God the Father), You are worthy to receive the glory and the
honor and the power” (Rev 4:11).


“Worthy is the Lamb (Jesus Christ) having been slain to receive the
power and riches and wisdom and strength and honor and glory and
blessing” (Rev 5:12).

The fact is, the worship given to Jesus reaches the Father and the worship given to Father reaches Jesus because they are One.
Who Created Everything?
The apostles also knew who created all things:

“You (God the Father) created all things, and through Your will they
exist and were created” (Rev 4:11).


“All things came into being through Him (Word aka Jesus), and without
Him not even one thing came into being that has come into being” (John
1:3).

God the Father also witnesses about Jesus:

“You, Lord (Jesus), at the beginning founded the earth, and the
heavens are works of Your hands. They will vanish away, but You will
continue; and they will all become old, like a garment, and You shall
fold them up like a covering, and they shall be changed. But You are
the same, and Your years shall not fail” (Heb 1:10-12).

[This is a clear reference to Yahweh in the OT. Now the Holy Spirit clearly shows here that God the Father calls Jesus the Yahweh of the OT who interacted with the patriarchs and prophets]
So, who created everything?
The answer is that Father and Son created everything together.
Conclusion
God the Father is called Lord by the apostles. Jesus Christ is called Lord by the apostles.
It would really be difficult to analyze each “Lord” to see whether it is Father or Jesus.
The fact is, excepting the time when the “Spokesperson/Word or the CEO” of God the Father became a Man, it would be almost impossible to distinguish between them in both OT and NT.
This is because “the Word was God and was with God”!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes, Jesus Christ is referred to as Lord and is implied, thus, to have the same divine, worshipable dignity as God the Father. Moreover, if one denies the Deity of Christ, it is necessarily a calumny on God and such a slanderer cannot have God as Father either (cf. 1 John 2:23).
That Jesus is prayed to as Lord is so clear, that only biased heretics can twist mercilessly the text to contrive their eisegetetic weirdnesses. For instance, does not Paul pray directly to Christ when he wants Him to liberate him from a demonic presence? "I asked the Lord three times to take it away from me. He answered me, “I am all you need. I give you My loving-favor. My power works best in weak people.” I am happy to be weak and have troubles so I can have Christ’s power in me" (2 Cor. 12:8-9). It is impossible that anybody in his right mind asks directly anybody lesser than God to liberate one from such a demonic infliction, but among the heretical so called theologians right mind is not to be sought. And how could Paul not pray to Him who enjoins all His followers to pray to Him: “If you ask Me anything in My name, I will do it” (John 14:14).
